# 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe

I'm trying to run the following code

```
def RSI(series, period):
 delta = series.diff().dropna()
 u = delta * 0
 d = u.copy()
 u[delta > 0] = delta[delta > 0]
 d[delta < 0] = -delta[delta < 0]
 u[u.index[period-1]] = np.mean( u[:period] ) #first value is sum of avg gains
 u = u.drop(u.index[:(period-1)])
 d[d.index[period-1]] = np.mean( d[:period] ) #first value is sum of avg losses
 d = d.drop(d.index[:(period-1)])
 rs = u.ewm(com=period-1, min_periods = period).mean() / \
 d.ewm(com=period-1, min_periods = period).mean()
 return 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)

    df['RSI'] = df.groupby(['Commodity'], as_index = False).apply(RSI(df, 14)).reset_index(level=0, drop = True)
```

I keep getting the following error:  "'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed".

However, when I use the following - it works:

```
df['RSI'] = RSI(df['Close'], 14)
```

What am I missing here?  I need to insert a Groupby to make this work correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to pass an argument to `RSI` at `apply(RSI(df, 14))`? IINM the `apply` method receives a function that takes a dataframe row as argument and `RSI(df, 14)` is not returning such function.

Comment: Hi Paulo, I have modified the function as above.  Note that I can get it work on the second df['RSI'] statement.  But I need the groupby to work.

Comment: The apply method takes a function, for example, `.apply(RSI)` where the function signature is `RSI(row)` - check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for examples.

Comment: yes but it works when I dont use the groupby statement.  So there must be something else to make it work.

Comment: I guess `apply` is the wrong tool here. Sorry, I don't have time right now for writing a proper answer but I believe there is other approaches to get the same result using broadcast operations.

Comment: Check your brackets